Autoresponder Unable to Receive GET Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/subscribe'
I am trying to set up an autoresponder using Node.js and Nodemailer on my website, but it is not working as expected. After signing up, I get this in the browser: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/subscribe" and
 This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405.

I want to enable an auto-response for my newsletter when a user subscribes on my website. My website is using Node.js and Nodemailer. It is running, but after signing up, I get "http://127.0.0.1:5500/subscribe" in the browser and
This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405.


Not sure what you mean by autoresponder and how this is related to a HTTP request. Besides that how should we know why http://127.0.0.1:5500/subscribe results in a 405 error if we don't know what is acutally running on  5500 and how it is setup?

Why do you have to paragraphs with mostly the same wording? Are those meant to be the same and should only one of those be there?
